# Create input text that starts with certain prefix and is not errasable

Tags: reactjs

i want to create a simple input text that starts with a certain choosen prefix and it starts writing right after that prefix and when the user deletes the input text it won't delete the prefix it stays there , is there a solution to make it happen ?

```
                       <div className="position-relative form-group">
                            <img src="./redRisk.png" style={{ width: '2%' }} 
                               />
                               <input
                                name="titre"
                                id="exampleEmail"
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                 onChange={()=>{}}
                               />
                        </div>
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a component with the said prefix along with the input component and later submitting the input along the prefix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's doable, but i thing that option with styling text next to it is better

```
const prefix = 'prefix-'
```

```
 <div className="position-relative form-group">
      <input
          name="titre"
          id="exampleEmail"
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          ref={(target)=>{
            target.value = prefix
          }}
          onChange={(e)=>{
            const input = e.target.value
            e.target.value = prefix + input.substr(prefix.length)
          }}
      />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i appreciate that , it worked perfect !

Comment: I know it's been a very long time since you answered this but thank you so much, you just really helped me out! The only thing that needs updating if using this answer today that I can see is that `substr()` now needs to be replaced with `substring()` due to `substr()` now being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the prefix text to be editable you could just render it before the input and style the input accordingly:

```
<div className="position-relative form-group">
  <img src="./redRisk.png" style={{ width: '2%' }} />

  <div className="text-style">Prefix</div>
  <input
    name="titre"
    id="exampleEmail"
    type="text"
    className="form-control+matching-text-style"
    onChange={() => {}}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to set the input to start writing just after the Prefix ?

Comment: There's always a way, but do you want to have to deal with that complexity is the question. Why do you need the prefix to actually be in the input?

Comment: when i write a risk it starts with (R) and when it's an opportunity it starts with (O)